# Probability that each series in a pack of cards appears in a random sample

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This is from William Feller Vol 1 Chapter 4 Probability.

> A pack of cards consists of $s$ identical series, each containing $n$ cards numbered $1,2,\ldots, n$. A random sample of $r\ge n$ cards is drawn from the pack without replacement. Calculate the probability $u_r$ that each number is represented in the sample.

My solution : Select first card out n (s identical copies so one way of selecting them), next card out of n-1 and so on such that each represent a unique number between 1 to n and then select the rest of (r-n) cards out of ns-n cards.

So it will be $$\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\ldots(1)}{n!} \frac{^{(ns-n)}C_{r-n}}{^{ns}C_{r}} = \frac{^{(ns-n)}C_{r-n}}{^{ns}C_{r}}  $$

But Feller volume 1 gives some other solution of the form
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k} {^{n}}C_{k} {\frac{(ns-ks)_{r}}{(ns)_r}}$$

Why so ?

Comment: Check what happens to your argument in a special case, say $s=2$ And $r=n+1$.

Answer (score 1):

In a selection of $r$ objects, let $A_k$ denote the event that only a particular set of $k$ numbers of $1,2,\ldots, n$ are missing among the chosen. That is, all the $r$ are chosen from the remaining $ns-ks$ and also contain each of the remaining $n-k$ of $1,2,\ldots,n$. The probability for this is 
\begin{align*}
\frac{(ns-ks)_r}{(ns)_r}
\end{align*}
Since there are $\binom{n}{k}$ choices for a subset of $k$ elements, the probability that $k$ are missing is 
\begin{align*}
\binom{n}{k}\frac{(ns-ks)_r}{(ns)_r}
\end{align*}
Hence by Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion, the probability that all $n$ are represented in the selection is 
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac{(ns-ks)_r}{(ns)_r}
\end{align*}

Comment: So basically it is 1 - probability that at least one number is missing. But why can't we do it by considering that first select n unique numbers then select rest (r-n) numbers ?